# Cordova not loading particular websites using InAppBrowser plugin

Tags: javascript, apache, cordova, self, inappbrowser

We're trying to load an MVC5 app into our Cordova project using the InAppBrowser plugin. This is the javascript code:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.apache.org', '_self', 'location=yes');
```

Now, this works just fine with most websites, however I've noticed that some website refuse to open with _self (_blank works 100% of the time), including google.com and the MVC app in particular which we want to load. Does someone know what might cause these sites not to load? We've already tried whitelisting them in the config.xml